# PHPExcel: Import csv file with line break in cells

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I'm trying to import a csv file with PHPExcel.

Some cells contains line breaks and when using the getRowIterator method, those line breaks are seen as a new excel row.

Example :

My data :

1. "abcd"; "ab cd"; "ab{line break}cd"; "abcd";

What i get in php :

1. "abcd"; "ab cd"; "ab";
2. "cd"; "abcd";

How can i avoid that behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you CSV file uses proper quoting of string values, then PHPExcel should be perfectly capable of handling line breaks in cells; but if necessary you can try setting the actual line ending manually using the CSV Readers setLineEnding() method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean about _quoting of string values_ ? I put quote in the original post just to indicate it was a cell, there isnt actual quote in my data. Btw, the content cut by line breaks are getting a **"** at the beggining in php.

Comment: If there aren't quotes in the actual CSV file, then any line ending will be treated as end of row. If a cell/string value is wrapped in quotes, then it may contain line endings within the cell itself, and PHPExcel will treat those as part of the cell content. While the CSV "standard" is fairly loose and undefined, there are certain conventions: see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 and  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I read the file with excel so i didnt know about the quotes. I opened it with a text editor and it seems to match the format, the data is quoted and the line break is **CR|LF**. Is that why the problem occur ?

Comment: _6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
       should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:

       "aaa","b CRLF
       bb","ccc" CRLF
       zzz,yyy,xxx_

Comment: Yes, that's the relevant part of the CSV standard: if line breaks are correctly quoted when they appear in a field, then PHP's fgetcsv() will work correctly, and PHPExcel is able to read the field correctly

Comment: Then I dont know why PHPExcel keeps doing that. **EDIT:** It works with fgetcsv but not with PHPExcel.

Comment: PHPExcel uses fgetcsv(), so I can't understand why one should work and not the other, or why it should work when I've tested it myself: guess I've been assigned my homework for this evening then.... try and create a correctly formatted csv file where fgetcsv() reads it correctly but PHPExcel doesn't work.... unless you can provide an example file

Comment: Thanks for your time, here is a sample : http://expirebox.com/download/3a6ccc0a9c61df706e89a93ead6707c3.html

Comment: There is a similar problem with comma.

Comment: Problem #1 is that it looks like it's using a semi-colon (`;`) as a field separator, not a comma (`,`).... By default, PHPExcel (and fgetcsv()) will assume a comma separator unless you explicitly tell it that another character should be used

Comment: OK, I didnt write the code i have and PHPExcel isnt use the way its intended, my bad, should have checked that first. Thanks again.